# Transforming a csv data frame into an html table

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I would like to transform my `dataframe` into an `html` table. I don't know how I can do it. Please assist me

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from prettytable import PrettyTable

data=pd.read_csv('C:/Users/ABDILLAH/Desktop/datasets/Angular/AngularDataset.csv')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pandas actually has a pretty nifty tool function to_html that will do exactly what you're saying: convert a dataframe into an html table. The exact documentation is available [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html), but essentially something as follows should work, depending on your csv structure:

```
data.to_html()
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simple as pandas renders a DataFrame as an HTML table.

```
import pandas
data = pd.read_csv("myfile.csv")
data.to_html('newFile.html')
```